# How can I rewrite this query without a subquery

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT p.*,
       pc.category_id
FROM (product AS p) 
LEFT JOIN product_category AS pc 
  ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
WHERE pc.category_id IN
    (SELECT pc.category_id
     FROM (product AS p)
     LEFT JOIN product_category AS pc 
        ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
     WHERE p.product_id = '4')
```

Please Help
How can I rewrite this query without a subquery.

Thankyou

Comment: You could start by formatting it in a way that makes it easier to read

Comment: You could start making it into multiple lines and indent. How to indent it is widely discussed and is a discussion - not a question with an answer. If you wish, use [`SQLFormat`](http://sqlformat.org/)

Comment: http://sqlformat.org/

Comment: Is the question about formatting or about writing a simpler query that produces the same output?

Comment: in addition to simply formatting, you might consider using a join instead of the in+subselect. but then, it is not really about readability, but optimizing IN, which has an infinite number of questions+answers already.

Comment: Thank you. I mean writing. I would like a simpler query.

Comment: So you need a query to: List of all products sharing some or all of the product categories as that of Product_ID 4?

Answer (score 1):

format it to be more readable:

```
SELECT p.*, pc.category_id 
FROM (product as p) 
LEFT JOIN product_category as pc 
ON p.product_id = pc.product_id 
WHERE pc.category_id IN 
    (SELECT pc.category_id 
     FROM (product as p) 
     LEFT JOIN product_category as pc 
     ON p.product_id = pc.product_id 
     WHERE p.product_id = '4')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the query correctly, it selects all the products that belongs to the categories that contain the product with `product_id = 4` (the table `product_category` is the many-to-many relationship between products and categories).

This query should return the same result set:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*, pc.category_id
FROM product p
    INNER JOIN product_category pc ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
    INNER JOIN product_category p2 ON p2.category_id = pc.category_id
        AND p2.product_id = '4'
```

**How it works:**

It matches all the products `p` with the categories (`pc.category_id`) they belong to then with the other products (`p2.product_id`) that belongs to these categories (`p2.category_id = pc.category_id`) and have `p2.product_id = 4`.

The `DISTINCT` keyword is needed because otherwise each product will appear multiple times when it shares at least 2 categories with another product. More products and categories involved in the sharing will increase the number of duplicates even more.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need: A List of all products sharing some or all of the product categories as that of Product_ID 4

```
SELECT p.*, PC.category_ID
FROM  Product P
INNER JOIN Product_Category PC
 on P.Product_ID = PC.Product_ID
INNER JOIN PRoduct_Category PC2
 on PC.Product_Category_ID = PC2.Product_Category_ID
 and PC2.Product_Id = 4
```

This basically joins to product category a second time to get a set of data which consists of product 4 categories.  It then joins to a set of data containing all products and categories which will exclude those products which don't share at least one category.